# Bin timestamp into custom periods

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to pandas and I am running into a roadblock. I have a data-frame that contains a time-stamp. I would like to add a column to my data-frame which would contain custom period names (strings). For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('01-01 00:00', periods='72', freq='H'))
```

I would like to create a column `df['Periods']`which would contain custom periods name. For instance, `Period1` if the time-stamp is between `01-01 00:00` and `01-02 00:00`, `Period2`otherwise.

I was thinking about using `cut` but the bins attribute seems to only take integers.

What would you do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `df` initialization `periods` must be a number not a string.

I guess approach on how to handle this will depend on how many periods to you want to have.

There are at least couple of ways:

Setup periods:

```
from datetime import time

morning_start = time(7)
morning_end = time(12)
evening_start = time(18)
evening_end = time(22)

periods = {'morning':[morning_start, morning_end], 'evening':[evening_start, evening_end]}
```

Approach 1.

```
def f(x, periods=periods):
    for k, v in periods.items():
        if x.hour >= v[0].hour and x.hour < v[1].hour:
            return k
    return 'unknown_period'
```

Approach 2.

```
for k, v in periods.items():
    df['periods'] = np.where(((v[0].hour <= df.t.apply(lambda x: x.hour)) & (df.t.apply(lambda x: x.hour) <= v[1].hour)), k, 'unknown_period')
```

With the two periods that are defined 1st approach works faster:

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 658 µs per loop
```

vs. 2nd:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 3.31 ms per loop
```

In both cases with only two periods you could make it one-line expression (without the need to loop through the `periods`):

```
df['periods'] = np.where((morning_start.hour <= df.t.apply(lambda x: x.hour)) & (df.t.apply(lambda x: x.hour) <= morning_end.hour), 'morning', 'evening')
```